# Wordpress Dashboard broken, displays “flashbacks” of comments/plugins/updates

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

I’m using the **latest version of Wordpress** (4.7.4).
I have something very weird going on in my Dashboard. Not sure when this started.
Can’t say for sure it started with the latest version of Wordpress or not.

My Dashboard became completely useless.
It’s like it’s showing me a flashback of a Dashboard from a few days or hours ago:

- Comments I’ve deleted in the Dashboard (hitting “trash”) are suddenly back there, awaiting my moderation.
- Plugins I’ve deactivated or even deleted are all back there and according to Dashboard still running (while in my FTP folder they’re certainly gone).
- The plugin page cannot be trusted anymore as it shows some plugins are activated that aren’t and vice versa. I have to check on my actual website to confirm which ones are running.
- Updates aren’t shown correctly. Once I’ve updated a plugin, a few minutes later it shows me again that there’s a new update.

As you can tell it’s all pretty much the same phenomenon.
It’s as if I’m seeing an older version of my Dashboard.

Not sure what else is broken.
The only other thing I noticed is that even on my actual blog I still see a comment. Blog post says “1 comment”, but the actual comment doesn’t show up.

At first, this all sounds like a “cache problem”.
But I’ve already turned off all caching:

No caching plugin installed

- Turned off server caching via htaccess
- Disabled leverage browser caching
- Emptied my own browser cache

**Other things I tested:**

- Turn off all plugins.
- Switch to the standard Wordpress theme “Twenty Twelve”
- I tried WP_DEBUG, but nothing related shows up.
- I researched the internet, but nobody has described a similar problem, so I suppose this is not a common Wordpress issue.

The issue remains.

Unfortunately I’m not a developer and don’t know too much about the Wordpress codex etc.
But to me it sounds that the mistake is definitely not in the plugin or theme folder.
The problem is that I’ve **reached the point where I really cannot turn off plugins via Dashboard** properly anymore. It’s so annyoing!

**My questions are:**

- Is it safe to assume that this is related to the Wordpress core
  files?
- What files exactly are in “charge of” the Dashboard?
- Should I just try to re-download the newest Wordpress version and replace a few files (if so which ones)?
- Should I do a clean Wordpress re-install or would that be too drastic?
- Any other suggestions?

**EDIT:**
**Additionally I tried now:**

- I manually downloaded the newest version of Wordpress and did just as
  described on the Wordpress.org website. I manually replaced wp-admin,
  wp-include folders and all root files. The issue remains...

The way my Dashboard is right now, I really can’t use it.
Please advice!

Comment: Could you provide more information about your web server you are running it on? Database, etc.

Comment: @BerenddeGroot Sure. Hawk Host, PHP 7.1, Litespeed, MYSQL. Anything else I shall provide, and I'll do it gladly. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted my host service again.
They just gave me the same line to insert into my .htaccess file and I told them I already tried it and it didn't work.

I then showed them my **.htaccess file** and they deleted the whole part that concerned their server caching.
Now **server caching is completely off** and everything works again.

Still not sure why this previously never caused issues.
In the end, it had nothing to do with Wordpress.

I hope this answer will help people who run into similar problems.